# Is this normed linear space a Banach space?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite measure and $1 < p_1 < p_2 < \infty$. Consider the linear space $L^{p_2} (E)$ normed by $||.||_{p_1}$ . Is this normed linear space a Banach space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left about three wrong comments due to mixing up $p_1$ and $p_2$, so let me say it the right way this time.

It is not a Banach space, in general.  Take $E = (0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure, for instance, and $p_1 = 2$, $p_2 = 4$.  The function $f(x) = x^{-1/3}$ is in $L^2$ but not in $L^4$.  Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^4$ which converges, in $L^2$ norm, to $f$; for instance, $f_n = \max(f, n)$.  This sequence is Cauchy in $L^2$ norm, but it does not converge in $L^2$ norm to any element of $L^4$.

One can show it is only a Banach space if $E$ is a finite union of atoms.  In such a case $L^{p}(E)$ is finite dimensional for all $p$ and so all norms are equivalent.

For practical purposes, you should expect that a given vector space has at most one "reasonable" Banach norm, up to equivalence. A second norm on a Banach space is either equivalent to the first one, or is incomplete, or is some pathological non-constructive axiom of choice monster.  You can read more about this in Schechter, *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations*. In this case the norms are clearly not equivalent (unless, as mentioned, $L^p(E)$ is finite dimensional), and they are both very explicit, so we expect they can't both be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Okay lets suppose that $(L^{p_2},\|.\|_{p_1})$ is a Banach space then the map
\begin{align*}
\Phi:(L^{p_2},\|.\|_{p_2}) &\to (L^{p_2},\|.\|_{p_1}), \\f &\mapsto f
\end{align*}
is not only continuous but also bicontinuous. This follows from the fact that $\|.\|_{p_1} \leq C \|.\|_{p_2}$ and [the open map theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)). Now this yields that there is a $K>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|\Phi(f)\|_{p_1} \geq K \|f\|_{p_2} \\
\|f\|_{p_1}\geq K \|f\|_{p_2}
.
\end{align*}
Now take a sequence of sets $A_n \subseteq E$ with $0<\lambda(A_n)\to 0$ ($\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure) and consider the previous inequality
\begin{align*}
\lambda(A_n)^{\frac{1}{p_1}} \geq K \lambda(A_n)^{\frac{1}{p_2}} \quad \text{for all} \quad n\in\mathbb{N}\\
\lambda(A_n)^{\frac{1}{p_1}-\frac{1}{p_2}} \geq K \quad \text{for all} \quad n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
But $\frac{1}{p_1}-\frac{1}{p_2}>0$ because of our assumptions, this leads to $K = 0$ which contradicts $K>0$. So it can't be Banach space